# C# yield return not returning an item as expected

Tags: c#, yield

I have following code:

```
private void ProcessQueue()
{
    foreach (MessageQueueItem item in GetNextQueuedItem())
        PerformAction(item);
}

private IEnumerable<MessageQueueItem> GetNextQueuedItem()
{
    if (_messageQueue.Count > 0)
        yield return _messageQueue.Dequeue();
}
```

Initially there is one item in the queue as ProcessQueue is called.
During PerformAction, I would add more items to _messageQueue.  However, the foreach loop quits after the initial item and does not see the subsequent items added.

I sense that somehow the initial state of the queue is being captured by yield.

Can someone explain what is happening and give a solution?

Comment: The code would be simpler if you just use a while loop in ProcessQueue rather than using an enumerator.  Enumerators are quite handy, but they can be overkill for simple loop processing.

Comment: Good comment - though I came to the above through a series of refactoring and I was just caught up in the curiosity chase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program does exactly what you instructed to do: it yields one item if `Count > 0` - and yields zero items otherwise.

To return items *until* the queue becomes empty, try:

```
while (_messageQueue.Count > 0)
```

Comment: @Obalix: you are wrong. There will never be a race condition, since items are added during PerformAction from the same thread. The question is not about accessing the queue from other threads - and `yield` will not turn the code magically into multi-threaded.

Comment: Where is the bit about race condition??

Comment: @Jiho: if the queue can be accessed and/or modified by multiple threads simultenously, the code you have posted will not work as expected.

Comment: Noted but I don't have a concern for threading at the moment.
As for my question regarding the race condition, I meant that I didn't see where Obalix talks about race conditions.  Was that deleted somehow?

Comment: @Jiho: "Noted but I don't have a concern for threading at the moment": I suppose that this is exactly why he deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

`yield return` actually pauses execution and does a fake return (it yields a value) until the next one is requested.  In this case, what happens is you check if the count is > 0 and then yield the next value.  When the next one is requested, your if statement isn't checked again, it returns to the line after the `yield return` which is the end of the method and thus it's done.

Comment: I like this explanation better though; it's clearer in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "YIELD"

Used in an iterator block to provide a value to the enumerator object or to signal the end of iteration.

I have an excellent record of reading syntax statements wrong but I think this means it has to be in an iterator block and the one you wrote is not.

Perhaps change your code to;

```
foreeach (MessageQueItem item In GetNextQuedItem()
{
     if (_messageQueue.Count > 0)
     {   
         yield return _messageQueue.Dequeue();
     } else { 
         yield break;
     }

}
```